# Having Designing issue with bootstrap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap with visual studio 2010,i am having problem of designing ,when i switch to design tab in VS the Design is not correctly rendered and every time i need to fire up my browser to see the design ,I want to to use Bootstrap with asp.net and c# ,Is there any fix for this or any alternative available.

Comment: Most serious developers never touch the designer. I know that isn't an answer to your question, but I personally wouldn't waste time trying to get the designer to work

Comment: i am newbie in designing,i just know the rules not done much practical

Comment: The best advice as far as I'm concerned is that unless you write HTML from scratch (actually writing every tag by hand) you will not fully understand what is going on in your page. Designers do their best, but add lots of completely unnecessary code that is simply not required. You'll be a much better developer

Comment: Thanks ,i will do that ,i am having one more problem that is some of my bootstrap controls are not working with asp.net pages and when i copy the same code in html pages they work.why is this happening?

Comment: That question has nothing to do with your original question. Please ask a brand new one with as many details as possible (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))